# Usage of “Speisekarte” and “Menü”

Tags: difference

I just came across these words *Speisekarte* and *Menü.* Can they be used interchangeably? If not,why?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please report why you think these words can be used interchangeably and what you have found so far?

Comment: I'm learning the language using an application called Duolingo . It highlights the use of these words as such . I checked the meaning of Menü on the net , where it is defined as ' Set meal '

Comment: Well, then. How does that not answer your question?

Comment: @Ingmar Admittedly, searching for *Speisekarte* should have cleared this in a jiffy, but *Menü* can be tricky. So I chose to answer... If this gets closed, I can delete my answer.

Comment: This is not an unreasonable question, as both mean *menu* in English.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They can't be used interchangeably because *they mean two very different things*.

- A **Speisekarte** is the list of food items / dishes that are offered in a restaurant. Sometimes drinks are included, sometimes there is a separate *Getränkekarte* for beverages or *Weinkarte* for wines.
- A **Menü** is a sequence of dishes that are served at one meal. A typical *Menü* would contain three courses, but the number can be indicated by a numeric expression plus the term *Gang*, (= course) so a *[Dreigangmenü](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dreigangmenue)<sup>1</sup>* consists of three, a *Fünfgangmenü* of five courses.

Your ***set meal*** is actually a bit misleading:
You can "build your own menu" by choosing a sequence of dishes from the *Speisekarte*, e.g. a starter, a main dish and a dessert. A set meal is a pre-combined menu that is either offered by the restaurant (e.g. "Menü des Tages", often at a reduced price) or pre-ordered, especially if visiting the restaurant with a larger group where ordering individually might pose a logistic problem for the kitchen.

---

Side notes:
Don't confuse the German *Menü* with the English *menu*, the latter has *both* the meaning of "available items" and "sequence of dishes".
Also the menu on a computer is (confusingly, IMHO) called *Menü* in German...

---

<sup>1</sup>  also valid: *[Drei-Gänge-Menü](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Drei_Gaenge_Menue)* and *Dreigängemenü*

Comment: Müsste es nicht "Dreigängemenü" statt "Dreigangmenü" heißen?

Comment: @Robert - das ist der Begriff der mir vertrauter ist. Duden nennt [Dreigamgmenü](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dreigangmenue) und empfiehlt [Drei-Gänge-Menü](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Drei_Gaenge_Menue) statt des (ebenso gültigen) Dreigängemenü. Ist wahrscheinlich dasselbe wie beim Fahrrad. Edit zur Vollständigkeit folgt, danke.

Comment: @Stephie: Wenn wir schon dabei sind, bitte auch "dreigängiges Menü".

Comment: Nach meiner Auffassung: Dreigangschaltung (Fahrrad), Fünfganggetriebe (Auto), Drei-Gänge-Menü (Restaurant). Kann aber nicht ausschließen, dass es da regionale Unterschiede gibt...

Answer (score 2):

A *Speisekarte* literally means *dish card*, and is list of dishes served by the restaurant. It is what an American would mean by the word *menu*.

A German *Menü* is something rather different. It represents a full "meal" of multiple courses. There can be several German *Menüs* listed on a single *Speisekarte*. The two words are not the same in German and cannot be used interchangeably.

Put another way, the word *Menü* is a "false friend" in German.